# Automating CLI application which opens another GUI window

Tags: python, subprocess, pytest, popen, rpa

I have a program `JLinkExe` which I can start in Windows/Powershell:

```
& "C:\Program Files\SEGGER\JLink\JLink.exe" -nogui 1
```

Or in Linux/WSL:

```
JLinkExe -nogui 1
```

In both cases program starts, prints some data and presents a `J-Link>` *prompt*.

```
SEGGER J-Link Commander V7.88k (Compiled Jul  5 2023 15:02:18)
DLL version V7.88k, compiled Jul  5 2023 15:00:41

Connecting to J-Link via USB...O.K.
Firmware: J-Link STLink V21 compiled Aug 12 2019 10:29:20
Hardware version: V1.00
J-Link uptime (since boot): N/A (Not supported by this model)
S/N: 775087052
VTref=3.300V


Type "connect" to establish a target connection, '?' for help
J-Link>
```

At this point user needs to start inputting commands *(each ending with enter/newline)* eventually leading to flashing of some firmware to the target embedded system. The commands that I have to send are:

```
connect
STM32F429ZI
SWD
4000
erase
loadbin program.elf , 0x0
q
```

The problem here is that after command `4000` application `JLinkExe` spawns a GUI window where user needs to use a mouse to click <kbd>Accept</kbd> button.

---

I want to write a `python3` & `pytest` script that will automate this so I managed to do this so far:

```py
import pytest
import subprocess
import pyautogui
import sys
import shutil
import os

JLINK_SERIAL = "115081052"
TARGET = "STM32F429ZI"


@pytest.fixture
def canScriptRun() -> None:

    # Newline for nicer pytest formatting.
    print("\n")

    printSeparator()

    # Check whether script is ran by superuser / admin.
    if (os.name == "nt"):
        print("Operating system: NT compliant")
        if (os.access("Program Files", os.W_OK) is False):
            print("User: not admin (continue)")
        else:
            print("User: admin")
    elif (os.name == "posix"):
        print("Operating system: Posix compliant")
        if (os.access("/etc/", os.W_OK) is False):
            print("User: not superuser (exit)")
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            print("User: superuser")

    printSeparator()


@pytest.fixture
def flash(canScriptRun) -> None:

    # JLinkExe child process creation.
    if (os.name == "nt"):
        p = subprocess.Popen(
            [r"C:\Program Files\SEGGER\JLink\JLink.exe", "-nogui",  "1"],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            universal_newlines=True,
            text=True,
            shell=True
        )
    elif (os.name == "posix"):
        p = subprocess.Popen(
            ["JLinkExe", "-nogui", "1"],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            universal_newlines=True,
            text=True
        )

    # Send newline-separated commands to the process & leave the running
    # process as it is.
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate(
        input="connect\nSTM32F429ZI\nS\n4000\n",
        timeout=None
    )
    print(stdout)
    print(stderr)

    # Locate & click the GUI accept button based on it's screenshot saved in project folder.
    buttonCenterLocation = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("accept.png")
    pyautogui.move(buttonCenterLocation, 1)
    pyautogui.click()


def printSeparator() -> None:

    terminalWidth = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
    for i in range(0, terminalWidth):
        print('-', end='')


def test_tests(flash) -> None:

    # Newline for nicer pytest formatting.
    print("\n")

    pass
```

Once command `4000` executes a GUI window appears prompting me to click <kbd>Accept</kbd> button *(screenshoot)*, but mouse will not move to that position and will not make a click. This is because when GUI window is displayed `JLinkExe` is blocked and script also waits...

[image]

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `subprocess.Popen.communicate(timeout=None)` blocks the python script until the external program terminates, so your pyautogui block is never reached unless the window is closed.

Just call that with a finite timeout, suppress the exception and move on.

Note that this means you won't be able to read stdout and stderr until the process is terminated!

```py
@pytest.fixture
def flash(canScriptRun) -> None:

    # ...

    try:
        p.communicate(
            input="connect\nSTM32F429ZI\nS\n4000\n",
            timeout=10
        )
    except subprocess.TimeoutError:
        pass


    buttonCenterLocation = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("accept.png")
    pyautogui.move(buttonCenterLocation, 1)
    pyautogui.click()

    (sdtout, stderr) = p.communicate()

    print(stdout)
    print(stderr)
```

---

##### Additional thoughts

Pytest is really not the adequate resource for what you want to do, which is **Robotic Process Automation (RPA)**

There are a bunch of RPA libraries for Python, research those instead: https://pypi.org/search/?c=Framework+%3A%3A+Robot+Framework

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, but my customer wants pytest.

Comment: @71GA pytest is a runner, it does not provide any functionality to interact with UI elements. RPA libraries N1ngu mentioned do provide functionality to interact with UI and while they where mostly written for "Robot Framework",  they can be used from plain old python too and thus also from pytest.

Comment: I think I now understood the issue and added something else that I hope helps you. `pyautogui` is the adecuate resource for what you are doing but I still feel the `pytest` requirement is odd.